# Confuse about how to use **kwarg

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I'm new to programming, hoping someone can help clarify some concept to help me learn.

I think I understand ** , the ** convert kwarg into keyword and then pass to function.

I'm not really sure why I need to use ** twice though. Specifically, why do I need to explicitly pass in **param (vs just param) when it was already in the function definition that I will be passing in an kwarg

```
class Main(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def render(self, template, **kwarg):
        blah

class Test(Main):
    params = dict(a=1, b=2)
    self.render(template, params) #this doesn't work

    self.render(template, **params) 
    #this work, but I don't understand why do I need the ** again
    #when its already in the original render function?
```

Comment: Have you read the tutorial? A single * translates positional arguments into a list, 2 ** translate named args into a dict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is that though the symbol (`**`) is the same, the [*operator*](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) is different:

```
def print_kwargs(**all_args):
    # Here ** marks all_args as the name to assign any remaining keyword args to
    print all_args

an_argument = {"test": 1}

# Here ** tells Python to unpack the dictionary
print_kwargs(**an_argument)
```

If we don't explicitly unpack our arguments in the call to `print_kwargs` then Python will throw a `TypeError`, because we have provided a positional argument that `print_kwargs` doesn't accept.

Why doesn't Python automatically unpack a dictionary into `kwargs`? Mostly because "explicit is better than implicit" - while you *could* do automatic unpacking for a `**kwarg`-only function, if the function had any explicit arguments (or keyword arguments) Python would not be able to automatically unpack a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks, this make more sense now. When would it automatically unpack? Is it better to still pass it in with double asterisk even if it automatically unpack because explicit is better than implicit? or does that cause an error.

Comment: @vagavince - it will *never* automatically unpack, because explicit is better than implicit ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a method like this...

```
>>> def fuct(a, b, c):
...   print a
...   print b
...   print c
```

and you have got dictionary with required params to sent to method

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

so by using ** (double asteric) you can unpack the dictionary and send to function

```
>>> fuct(**d)
1
2
3
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `*args` is used by the non-keyword arguments. A single `*` unpacks a list or tuple to elements, two `*`s unpack a dict to the keywords.